# How can I verify curl response before passing to bash -s?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a script that looks like:

```
curl -sSL outagebuddy.com/path/linux_installer | bash -s
```

Users can install a linux client for the site using the command that is provided to them. I'm thinking there should be an intermediary step that verifies the `curl` had a 2XX response and downloaded the content successfully before passing it to `bash`. How can I do that?

Comment: You could use the `--fail` flag, which will suppress the output and return a non-zero status for responses that indicate failure.

Comment: In addition to hmm's comment, see: [Can I make cURL fail with an exitCode different than 0 if the HTTP status code is not 200?](https://superuser.com/a/1249678/340330)

Comment: You know if it's a 2XX response before the server even starts to write the data, since the header comes first. Thus, `curl --fail` suffices, making the proposed duplicate above on-point.

Comment: I'd want to inspect what I'm running before piping to Bash anyway...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, `--fail` works great! @BenjaminW., as would I. This is a quote directly from the installer page: "If you would like, feel free to have your IT personnel review the code that will run on your system." the latter part of that text is a link to the page which gets `curl`d and then piped into bash.

Comment: @hmm if you add your response as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: If that's the answer you want, this question is a duplicate and can be closed as such.

Comment: As stated, I agree the question is a duplicate. Perhaps edit the question to include a requirement that the transfer completes successfully and accept one of these other answers to benefit someone else having that requirement.

Comment: Charles has shared more information that I didn't understand, so I think I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a user-managed temporary file:

```
if script=$(curl --fail -sSL "$url"); then
  bash -s <<<"$script"
fi
```

Comment: The here string still creates a temporary file, doesn't it? Perhaps `if ! curl ...; then echo exit; fi | bash` instead, with a failed download simply executing a do-nothing script.

Comment: As an implementation detail (automatically deleted before even being used), but yes. It'd need to be something like, say, `bash -s < <(printf '%s\n' "$script")` to not have a temporary file, but that's *slower* than a temporary file on tmpfs, so I don't typically recommend it.

Comment: Simply adding `--fail` looks like it is enough to do the job. It doesn't get piped into `bash`. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Sure. Of course, `--fail` doesn't tell you if `curl` *actually succeeded* in retrieving the full content of the file, it only tells you if the file started with a HTTP 200 header. If it started with the correct header and was cut off halfway through (f/e), `curl` will already have written the half the data it received to stdout, and `bash -s` will presumably have started running it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it would allow half of the content to be downloaded and run! Thank you for adding that and helping me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having an intermediate file (which you certainly need if you want to make sure the `curl` command worked fully) then you can use:

```
if curl --fail -sSL <params> -o script.sh
then
    bash script.sh
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless there's some way to verify the content of `script.sh`. `curl` will exit 0 if it receives a response, even if that response is a 404, 403, etc.

Comment: Right, I see that the `--fail` is mandatory so we get a failure (in most cases). I updated my response.

Comment: "Certainly need" is a little strong, no? Even if one's going beyond the OP's request to just check the response code in the headers, one can store content in-memory rather than writing it to a file.

Comment: Nice one. Yes. As long as the script isn't too long, it will work just fine. The output could also be to a `tmpfs` file system. You still need to wait for the whole transfer to be done before you can decide whether it worked or not.

Comment: Simply adding `--fail` looks like it is enough to do the job. It doesn't get piped into `bash`. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Brandon, it does *half* the job -- it handles the non-200 case, it doesn't handle the 200-but-then-incomplete-download case.